# How to configure https in sails.js with .crt file

Tags: node.js, ssl, sails.js

I am running sailsJS on nodeJS and am trying to setup HTTPS, however I seem to be stuck. I can acess my site at http://example.com:443, but not at https://example.com

This question is similar to [how to configure https in sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17755916) except that I do not have .pem files, rather .crt and .key files that I got from Media Temple's QuickSSL.

This is what I have in *config/bootstrap.js*

```js
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    sails.config.express.serverOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/mysite.com.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/crt/mysite.com.crt'),
        ca: [fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/crt/mysite.com-geotrust.crt')]
    };
    cb();
};
```

I set the port number to 443 in *config/local.js*

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show the local.js and where you setup the https server. To me it looks like you are passing options to express. Express no longer creates the https server, it requires a https server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've experienced that the syntax you're using to configure express doesn't work for newer versions of sails so I updated it and it works with a self signed certificate. I moved the code to the local.config file since it is really an environment setting...The one thing I haven't tried is the certificate authority.

Here is what my config.local files looks like:

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  express: { serverOptions : {
      key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/mysite.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/mysite.com.crt')
    }
  },
  port: process.env.PORT || 443,
  environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
};
```

If that doesn't work you probably want to look at a few things:

1. If you're running on port 443 you need to call "sudo sails lift"
2. The file path must be valid (in my case the ssl directory was in the project root)
3. The file permissions must be readable for the files ('etc' in your example is normally only readable/executable by the root user)

Comment: This sets up https for me, however it later on causes req.session.passport to be undefined.  ( from google-passport ).  By any chance do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: You also need to have this for sessions:
module.exports.express = { customMiddleware: function (app) { app.use(passport.initialize()); app.use(passport.session()); } };

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation for SSL in sailsJS is still under works, but I found this on the [deployment page](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/wiki/deployment). In your **config/local.js**

```
module.exports.port = 80;
module.exports.environment = 'production';
module.exports.ssl = {
    cert: 'path/to/cert',
    key: 'path/to/key'
};
```

express and sailsJS have changed a lot. So you should try newer examples. I could not find many examples on this.

Comment: This does not work for me. Not sure if that is because I am using a "geotrust" signed certificate

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some configuration options to what others already mentioned I want to add that you can specify ciphers to be used like so ( preceding those that shouldn't be used with `!`):

```
  express: { serverOptions : { 
    key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/cert.pem'),
    ciphers: "DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:!AES256-SHA",
    honorCipherOrder: true //  this is necessary to make the ciphers order matter
    }   
  }
```

You can also pass other option that are stated on node's tls documentation page: http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that using
ciphers: "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES",
Will maker better results, try checking via

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Answer (score 0):

As an update from 0.9 to 0.10 , the local.js file should now have

```
ssl : {
key: fs.readFileSync(‘server.key’),
cert: fs.readFileSync(‘server.crt’)
}
```

instead of

```
express : {
        serverOptions : {
            key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt')
        }
    };
```