# Sails.JS HTTP + HTTPS

Tags: javascript, ssl, express, https, sails.js

I am trying to figure out how to lift a sails app that responds to both HTTP and HTTPS requests. I used the config/local.js method of configuring express like so (detailed [here](http://chrisrogers.me.uk/blog/sails-js-https-ssl/)):

```
 var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {

  port: process.env.PORT || 1337,
  environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',

  express: { serverOptions : {
    key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/cert.pem')
  }}

};
```

However, while this works, it results in the server ***only*** being able to serve HTTPS requests. Has anyone figured out how to get this done, without creating a separate HTTP only server that redirects to port 443 ?

Thanks

Comment: question: is your end goal to redirect http --> https? In otherwords if someone types http://example.com they get redirected to https://example.com. If that is the case you can do this a few different ways outside of sailsjs.

Comment: I ultimately just used nginx on the server and created a redirect rule for HTTP->HTTPS.

Comment: thats what i was going to suggest as nginx is probably the preferred method of serving a sailsjs app in production..

Comment: http://jsbot.io/node/http-and-https-handle-with-sailsjs This may be helpful

Answer (score 6):

1-Uncomment the path to your SSL Certificates in your local.js or add path to your SSL Certificates in your config/env/production.js.

```
    module.exports  = {
 ssl: {
     ca: require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/ca.crt'),
     key: require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/key.key'),
     cert: require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/cert.crt')
   },
 port: 443
}
```

2-Add a policies section in your config/env/production.js

```
    module.exports  = {
 ssl: {
     ca: require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/ca.crt'),
     key: require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/key.key'),
     cert: require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/cert.crt')
   },
 port: 443,
 policies: {
    '*': 'isHTTPS'
   }
}
```

3-Create a isHTTPS.js policy in your api/policies folder. This policy will redirect the HTTP request to HTTPS

```
  module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.secure) {
        // Already https; don't do anything special.
        next();
    } else {
        // Redirect to https.
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
};
```

4-Then we will edit the config/bootstrap.js file and listen to port 80 if the environment is production, so that we can redirect the requests to 443 i.e SSL

```
    var http = require( 'http' );
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
    //If the environment is production, then listen on port 80 
    if(sails.config.environment === "production") {
        http.createServer( sails.hooks.http.app ).listen( 80 );        
    }
    cb();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get http and https running with sails by modifying my configs/local.js file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var local = ... // Your default local.js settings should go here
if(require('optimist').argv.https) {
    local.express = {
        serverOptions : {
            key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt')
        }
    };
    local.port = 1338; // This port should be different than your default port
}
module.exports = local;
```

Now you will need to run your sails app twice. The first time type in your regular `sails lift` command. The second time run `sails lift --https`

This should allow you to have both http and https servers running off of the same codebase. As some other people have mentioned, nginx is a much better solution for handling this sort of this, but if you are doing local development and don't want to have to install nginx the solution above is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

### To have both HTTP & HTTPS, avoiding the redirection way:

Configure your **SSL key & cert** and **HTTPS port** in your */config/env/production.js*:

```
var fs = require( 'fs' );
module.exports = {
    port: 443,
    ssl: {
        key: fs.readFileSync( 'ssl_key.key' ),
        cert: fs.readFileSync( 'ssl_key.crt' )
    }
    //, ...
};
```

Then, **listen port 80** with a second HTTP server into */config/bootstrap.js*:

```
var http = require( 'http' );
module.exports.bootstrap = function ( cb ) {
    // ...
    if ( process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' )
        http.createServer( sails.hooks.http.app ).listen( 80 );
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been wondering for running sailsjs on HTTPS and after going back and forth here is the solution working for me.

1. I copied .crt and .key file in project directory under ssl folder
2. config/local.js updated with following as I'm using sailsjs 0.12.3

   ```
   ssl: {
     key: require('fs').readFileSync(require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/ssl/mykey.key')),
     cert: require('fs').readFileSync(require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/ssl/mycert.crt'))
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/862

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
    var express = require("express"),
         app = express();

    app.get('*', function(req,res) {  
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
    }).listen(80);

    cb();
};
```

If you are using sails **0.10.x** you may need to move this to module.exports.express (config/express.js) I'm not sure...

Comment: Above code is not working in sails 0.11.x. Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

As an update from 0.9 to 0.10 , the local.js file should now have

```
ssl : {
key: fs.readFileSync(‘server.key’),
cert: fs.readFileSync(‘server.crt’)
}
```

instead of

```
express : {
        serverOptions : {
            key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt')
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesnt look like there is a way to do this within sails at the moment so I ultimately just used nginx on the server and created a redirect rule for HTTP->HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

You must take care of **SSL** & **HTTPS** , If both use same port by proxy.

```
var express = require("express"),
     app = express();

app.get('*', function(req,res) {  

    if(req.isSocket){           
        return res.redirect('wss://' + req.headers.host + req.url)  
    }
    else{
        return res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)    
    }

}).listen(80);
```

Comment: where do you insert that code in a Sails.js project?