# What is the difference in configuring SSL on Sails, between set it on Nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, sails.js

I currently use this Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name www.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/domain.access.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:8086;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8086 https://www.domain.com;
    }
}
```

With this I have no problems, but I just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612738/sails-js-http-https) question that contains:

```
express : {
    serverOptions : {
        key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt')
    }
}
```

What is the best way to use https?. I'm hosted in Google Cloud and I have some pages in different port using `Nginx proxy_pass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you are thinking about completely removing Nginx and serving your node application directly. But if you don't plan to remove it completely, I would rather keep the configuration in Nginx to separate the responsibilities of the app and of the web server.

Using Nginx, you could also be ready to add functionalities like load balancing, reverse proxy caching, serving assets more efficiently, etc...

Comment: So. Do not I have to configure anything in Sails now?

Comment: If Nginx handles the SSL, the node.js app behind doesn't have to know anything about it. The client's browser will communicate with Nginx through https and Nginx will communicate with the node.js app through http. You just have to know that the communication will not be encrypted between Nginx and the app.