# Redirect all http request to https in sails js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to figure out how to redirect all HTTP request to HTTPS in Sails JS **0.11.0.**

I tried below code but it didnt work.

```
var express = require("express"),
     app = express();

app.get('*', function(req,res) {  

    if(req.isSocket){           
        return res.redirect('wss://' + req.headers.host + req.url)  
    }
    else{
        return res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)    
    }

}).listen(80);
```

Comment: HTTPS should never touch port 80, so i doubt you server hears anything there...

Comment: Use nginx front end server, follow this https://christiaanconover.com/blog/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-in-nginx

Comment: Is it possible without nginx? Did sails js provide any solution for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755916/how-to-configure-https-in-sails-js although I appreciate the answers there reference older versions of Sails.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used nginx for redirection.
Configuration in **nginx.conf** file

```
server {
        listen   80; 
        server_name example.com;
        rewrite     ^ https://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the http middleware in Sails.

In the config/http.js file, add a function like this to the middleware object.

```
requireHttps: function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
  }

  return next();
},
```

or like this (if you use an Amazon Elastic Load Balancer, which may communicate with your servers over http):

```
requireHttps: function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== undefined && req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] == 'http') {
    return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
  }

  return next();
},
```

And then simply add the 'requireHttps' to the order array in the middleware object, like this:

```
order: [
    'startRequestTimer',
    'cookieParser',
    'session',
    'passportInit',
    'passportSession',
    'bodyParser',
    'handleBodyParserError',
    'compress',
    'methodOverride',
    'poweredBy',
    '$custom',
    'requireHttps',
    'router',
    'www',
    'favicon',
    '404',
    '500',
],
```